# Jacobi Method for the linear systems (for first two iterations)

Tags: numerical-methods

I have the following 3 linear systems:
$$4x_1 + x_2 - x_3 = 5$$
$$-x_1 + 3x_2 + x_3 = -4$$
$$2x_1 + 2x_2 + 5x_3 = 1$$
for x^(0) = 0

Then, I write it as following:
$$x_1 =         -1/4x_2 + 1/4x_3 + 5/4$$
$$x2 = 1/3x_1          - 1/3x_3 - 4/3$$
$$x3 =-2/5x_1   -2/5x_2         + 1/5 $$
First iteration of Jacobi would be x^(1) = (5/4, -4/3, 1/5)

Then I perform the second iteration of the jacobi in below:
$$x_1 = -1/4*(-4/3) + 1/4*(1/5) + 5/4$$
$$x_2 = 1/3*(5/4) -1/3*(1/5) - 4/3$$
$$x_3 = -2/5*(5/4)  -2/5*(-4/3) + 1/5$$
For the second iteration of Jacobi, I got x^(2) = (1.63333, -0.9833333, 0.23333)

However, the solution shows that it is x^(2) = (1.2500000, -1.3333, 0.200000)
Could you please help me fixing my mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did the calculations and got the same answer as yours.

$x_0 = [0,0,0]$

$x_1 =  [1.2500   -1.3333    0.2000]$

$x_2 =  [1.6333   -0.9833    0.2333]$

SO it seems that you book seems to give $x_1$ as $x_2$, or it might have assumed $x_1=[0,0,0]$.

Hope it helps